# Повторный запрос Retrofit + RxJava

Tags: android, rxandroid

Изучаю RxJava. Прочитал статью в интернете, наткнулся на пример. Как мне в данном случае можно сделать еще один запрос, не меняя при этом тело слушателя (т.е subsribe)? Немного изменю вопрос, как для данного Observable выполнить еще один запрос с другим именем пользователя? При срабатывании какого то события, я должен сделать новый запрос на этот Observable
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавте в вопрос код как текст вместо картинки.

Answer (score 0):

Просто создайте метод, который принимает на вход имя пользователя(а его получайте из EditText или подобного).